# Is there a way to store multiple types of struct members pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have this code who's working just fine to retrieve the `foo` members by index.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int a = 42;
    int b = 16;
    std::string str = "hi";
};

int main()
{
    int Foo::*members[] = { &Foo::a, &Foo::b };
    Foo foo;

    std::cout << foo.*members[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I have an `std::string` on my struct that I want to be able to access the same way, is there a solution scalable to any type?

#### What I've tried:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

struct Foo {
    int a = 42;
    int b = 16;
    std::string str = "coucou";
};

int main()
{
    std::any Foo::*members[] = { (std::any Foo::*)&Foo::a, (std::any Foo::*)&Foo::b, (std::any Foo::*)&Foo::str };
    Foo foo;

    std::cout << std::any_cast<int>(foo.*members[0]) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I told myself that if store an array of `std::any`, that will work. In fact, this code does compile but crashes.

Any solutions?

Comment: what do you need it for? How is `foo.*members[1]` better than `foo.b` ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), perhaps? What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This code interpets an object of type `int` as an object of type `any` (this is undefined behavior). Instead you might store an array (or better a vector) of `any(*)(Foo*)` i.e. function pointers from Foo to any. Or a tuple of member pointers which would let you retain static type information about the member types.

Comment: This it typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) you have some ready solution of mystery problem and you ask to fix your solution instated asking what is better way to solve actual problem. I'm suspecting you need some meta data system, question is why?

Comment: @MarekR: You're right, but the question is still interesting in itself.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `std::tuple`:

```
std::tuple members{&Foo::a, &Foo::b, &Foo::str }; // C++17 CTAD
                                                  // else, use `std::make_tuple`
Foo foo;

std::cout << foo.*std::get<0>(members) << " " << foo.*std::get<2>(members) << std::endl;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9ebf301e24e7724)

Answer (score 1):

(I'll first say I agree with @MarekR's comment, that your question is likely an ["XY problem"](http://xyproblem.info/) and you probably don't actually want to do this at all... but still:)

This is an interesting challenge - and one which has been tackled by the "crazy genius" Antony Polukhin, in his [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) library - providing you are using the C++14 language standard, or later.

There is actually no need to store anything! The struct definition itself has all the information you need. Thus, when you write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "boost/pfr.hpp" // <- Not formally a part of Boost, yet...
                         //    you'll need to download the library from github

struct Foo {
    int a = 42;
    int b = 16;
    std::string str = "hi";
};

int main() {
    Foo my_foo;

    std::cout 
        << "a is " << boost::pfr::get<0>(my_foo) << ", "
        << "b is " << boost::pfr::get<1>(my_foo) << ", "
        << "and str is \"" << boost::pfr::get<2>(my_foo) << "\".\n";
}
```

you get:

```
a is 42, b is 16, and str is "hi".
```

just like you wanted.

To understand what the hell is going on, and where this black magic comes from, watch Antony's 2018 talk:

[Better C++14 reflections - Antony Polukhin - Meeting C++ 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlNUNxLtBI0)

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use a `string` as a pointer inside the Struct because it will not be pointing to nothing. Instead you can simply use like this:

```
    std::cout << foo.str << std::endl;
```

It will output your string as well.